# Google Play Music

Tags: music-player

It is possible to control Spotify with `spotify.el` and `helm-spotify` packages right from Emacs, and that's awesome.

But I couldn't find a simple way to control Google Play Music, has anyone figured it out?

Comment: One of the problems with this is that there is no official Google Music API. The only one I know if is in python, and is not for control but for managing your collection on Google Music.

Comment: There's new Google Music Desktop Player by Samuel Attard https://www.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.com and it seems to have some sort of api: https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/Google-Play-Music-Desktop-Player-UNOFFICIAL-/blob/master/docs/PlaybackAPI.md.
Now this could be controlled from inside Emacs. But you still have to run GPMDP app. So Emacs integration has almost no benefits in that case.